# Rails 4 fragment caching: view changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, view, memcached

In a Rails 4 project, let's say I use object-based fragment caching in a view, like this:

```
<% cache(current_user) do %>
  <%= current_user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Then whenever `current_user` is updated, the `current_user` cache key changes. That's great for invalidating the cache when the cache invalidation reason is that the object itself changed. But what about when the view changes? For example, what if I change the view code to display the capitalized user name (while `current_user` remains the same)?

```
<% cache(current_user) do %>
  <%= current_user.name.capitalize %>
<% end %>
```

It seems like object-based fragment caching will NOT invalidate the cache, even though the view should change. Does this mean that I must define cache keys that are versionized based on the version of the view, like the following?

```
# some_helper.rb
def user_name_cache_key(user)
  [user, "v2"] # un-capitalized name was v1
end

# some_view.html.erb
<% cache(user_name_cache_key(current_user)) do %>
  <%= current_user.name.capitalize %>
<% end %>
```

Perhaps this is obvious, but it's not at all mentioned in documentation or blog posts that discuss Rails caching; they all seem to focus on the object-updated-invalidation problem and ignore techniques for the view-updated-invalidation problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found out that the Cache Digests gem does this and is merged into Rails 4:

https://github.com/rails/cache_digests

Awesome.